# How can I use APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER to get a reference to a bootstrapped component?

Tags: angular

The Angular 2 API reference says the following about the APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER variable:

```
Variable Export export APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER

All callbacks provided via this token will be called for every component that is
bootstrapped. Signature of the callback:

(componentRef: ComponentRef) => void.
```

From this description, it sounds like I can somehow register a callback function that would allow me to grab a reference to every bootstrapped component on a page.  I would like to be able to do that so I could set properties of a component from outside of any Angular code.  Am I interpreting this description correctly and, if I am interpreting it correctly, how do I register my callback function?

Answer (score 2):

It is a token through which you can provide functions that will be called each time a component is bootstrapped:

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MyService,
    {provide: APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, multi: true, 
     useFactory: (myService) => 
        (componentRef:ComponentRef) => myService.rootComponent = componentRef 
     deps: [MyService]
    }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```